# C# how to make a child form topmost only inside the application?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, mdichild, mdiparent, topmost

I have 5 child forms in my c# application. one of the child forms named `childForm`opens another form `subForm`. What i want is, when `subForm` is open, user cannot click or do anything inside the application without closing `subForm`. But this should be contained in the application only. i.e When user wants to switch to another application without closing `subForm` he/she wont see `subForm` anymore, again if user switches to the c# application the `subForm` form must be on top and rest of the control must be disabled.

to create and show the `subForm` from within the `childForm` i wrote a button_click event

Comment: subForm.TopMost = true(); subForm.ShowDialog(); ?

Comment: cant show subForm as a dialog. i need to call a function in the subForm Class just after showing the subForm

Comment: put the function you need to call in the subForm ?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine your form contains an editbox, a Button and a close Button (x).

This may help if we have the same SDK.

```
Button.click += delegate{
Subform();
}

Public void Subform(){

Button closebutton = Resource.Id...;
Button Enter = Resource.id...;
Edittext Edit = Resource.Id...;

Enter.enabled = false;
Edit.editable = false;

Closebutton.click += delegate{
Mainform();
}
}
```